# problem in installing the ddsp python module 9ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ddsp')

Tags: python

I am trying to run [the below colab page](https://colab.research.google.com/github/magenta/ddsp/blob/master/ddsp/colab/demos/timbre_transfer.ipynb#scrollTo=3YLyiTwPfVCT) in my Ubuntu pc by the Conda Jupiter notebook as local, but I can not install the **ddsp** module and by running its [GitHub instruction](https://github.com/magenta/ddsp) like below (result of my tries could be seen [here](https://0bin.net/paste/XzrWsYMx#MqAlQ25fpLv3TNvvS3PvCfTxhc48UgH6fzGaLw+vI1p)):

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade ddsp
```

```
(tensorflow2_5) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~/Downloads$ sudo pip install --upgrade ddsp
WARNING: The directory '/home/so/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: ddsp in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from      
....


Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tfds-nightly->ddsp) (0.8)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I show some tings, but finally it is not installed and show the below error:

```
(tensorflow2_5) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~/Downloads$ python
Python 3.9.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jun 19 2021, 00:32:32) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ddsp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ddsp'
```

**Update:**

According to answer, I have tried to install the Python 3.9.5 with  `conda update python`  but after installing new python by `pip install --upgrade ddsp` and also `sudo pip install --upgrade ddsp` but it is not installed, as you can see [here](https://0bin.net/paste/D1OZfNII#NvU+3n01qqAd6+83gXmZYhVXzEVQYzau5FPdm3bSEXY).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you install `ddsp` using `sudo` which will install the module  as `root` user. That's why you see some python version 3.6 however your python version should be 3.9.5

Can you try to install without `sudo`?

Comment: No, I get error which could be seen [here](https://0bin.net/paste/aZeEOvWt#4b3o64JfkEWnUkIuB8MntisYYWwpGfyBde5YaCNtloo)

Comment: This time, the error is about dependency: `RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 7.0.x, 7.1.x or 8.0.x, got '10.0.0'. Be sure to set LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path.` Your LLVM version is too new. You might need to install older version of LLVM separately.

Comment: **Sorry** @nngeek, **the new python version** not work, I have updated the question. But I don't get what is the problem with **LLVM**!

Comment: @sosa, looks like your installation falling into a bad situation where you need to build  `llvmlite` package from source (`sdist`) (Ideally you should get the pre-built one). Here are some caveats listed in `llvmlite` installation page here: https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html . Key info is you need to compile LLVM by yourself, not using the system one.